# Riemannian manifolds are metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I've seen lots of casual claims that Riemannian manifolds (even without assuming second-countability) are metrizable. In the path-connected case, we can use arc-length to create a distance function. But how can one prove this without assuming path-connectedness (and second-countability)?

(Motivated by Problem 2-D of Milnor-Stasheff.)

Comment: I don't see how to define a metric for non-connected manifolds in general.

Comment: @user39082: I think you could handle each connected component separately, then use something like $d(x,y)=1$ for all pairs $x,y$ lying in distinct connected components.

Comment: No, this usually will not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: Anyway, the Smirnov metrization theorem mentioned in the answer below, of course does the job.

Comment: @user39082: Absolutely! I was being silly before.

Comment: @user39082 Of course this does not satisfies the triangle inequality, but you can first replace the distance by another one which is bounded from above by 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [Smirnov metrization theorem](http://planetmath.org/smirnovmetrizationtheorem), a space that is locally metrizable and paracompact is metrizable. So as each path component of a Riemannian manifold is metrizable as you explain, local metrizability clearly follows. Paracompactness is often required in the definition of a manifold (or that it is second countable, which implies paracompactness), which is why this claim is often made without additional hypotheses.

But even in the non-second countable case, as each path component of a Riemannian manifold is metrizable, it must be paracompact, again by Smirnov. An arbitrary disjoint union of paracompact spaces is paracompact, [a quick proof is here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/paracompact+topological+space#examples_2), so a Riemannian manifold must be paracompact.

See also [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54760/riemannian-metrics-on-non-paracompact-manifolds).

Answer (score 1):

Assume the manifold $M$ is connected. If there exists a piecewise-smooth path from $p$ to $q$ in $M$, then there exists such a path between $p$ and $q'$ for any $q'$ in a small closed neighborhood of $q$, since $M$ is locally path-connected. The set of such $q$ is thus open and closed in $M$, and so must be $M$ itself. It follows that $M$ is path-connected, and you can define the metric on $M$ by arc-length.

Comment: Wonderfully simple argument.

Comment: I guess I forgot that a connected and locally path-connected space is path-connected!

Comment: @squirrel: This is not yet a complete argument. "Arc-length" between two points is not well-defined, it depends on the choice of the piecewise smooth path; take, for example, the complement of a point in the Euclidean plane. Typically what one does it to take the infimum of arc length over all paths between $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Sure, but it sounds from the initial question that the poster can handle that part given path-connectedness.